# HighChart pointPlacement on y-axis

Tags: highcharts

For the same values, i want to place points on different locations on y-axis of a line chart.

tried pointPlacement but it only works for x-axis(category axis).

I want o/p as -

[image]

Here my values are same for all the lines but those lines aligned vertically.
If i use pointPlacement  then these lines will get aligned vertically, which i do not want.

Please suggest a property to align points vertically in highcharts.

Answer (score 0):

You can increase the `y` value of overlapping points or use some other visual concept to present the data: https://www.highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=39648

```
var series = [{
        data: [1, 4, 1, 3, 1]
    }, {
        data: [2, 4, 1, 3, 2]
    }, {
        data: [3, 4, 1, 3, 3]
    }],
    increaseValue = 0.1;

series[0].data.forEach(function(point, i) {
    series.forEach(function(s) {
        if (point === s.data[i]) {
            s.data[i] += increaseValue;
            increaseValue += 0.1;
        }
    });
    increaseValue = 0.1;
});
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/t369ep5h/